# Replace a string using sed in Linux

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace, sed

I want to replace following original string by replace string.

```
original_str="#22=SI_UNIT(*,*,#5,'','metre');"
replace_str="#22=SI_UNIT(*,*,#5,'','millimetre');"
sed -i "s/$original_str/$replace_str/" ./output/modified.txt
```

I have tried in different ways using 'sed'. However, it is not working. Does anyone have any idea?

The concept #22 is referenced to the other concept later in the same file. Is this the reason?

Please note that it is working fine for following string in the same bash script:

```
original_str="#103=CARTESIAN_POINT('P3',0.0,0.0,1.0,#72);"
replace_str="#103=CARTESIAN_POINT('P2',10.0,10.0,10.0,#72);"
sed -i "s/$original_str/$replace_str/" ./output/modified.txt
```

The concept #103 is not used in later concept in the same file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape characters that have a special meaning in `sed`, which in this case is `*`:

```
original_str='#22=SI_UNIT(\*,\*,#5,'','metre');'
replace_str='#22=SI_UNIT(*,*,#5,'','millimetre');'
sed -i "s/$original_str/$replace_str/" ./output/modified.txt
```

This will work.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I just realized, that you *can* escape `#`, which I find very interesting.

Comment: As I wrote, the later code (replace) is working. I want to replace first code. That is 'metre' to 'millimetre'. Additionally, I have tried with '\'. It does not work for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a regular expression metacharacter which does not match itself (or only does so coincidentally).  You need to escape it in the `original_str`.

```
sed -i "s/${original_str//\*/\\*}/$replace_str/" ./output/modified.txt
```

The `$(variable//substr/repl}` syntax is Bash-specific.  In the general case, you will need to escape any regex specials -- `[`,  `\`,  and `.` -- which is a bit harder to do in a general way in Bash.